# linux -- Create a directory structure with multiple names and spaces in them

Tags: shell

What I am trying to do:
from the command line create a directory structure to match musician names and album:

```sh
/path/Musician name/album name
```

I did some research and found 2 options for working with spaces in names:
escaping -- firstname\ lastname
using quotes -- "firstname lastname"

Current working directory showing owner and permissions:

```sh
pete@optiplex:~/tmp$ ls -al
total 48
drwxrwxrwx  3 pete pete  4096 Feb  4 08:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 57 pete pete 36864 Feb  3 21:45 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 pete pete  4096 Feb  4 08:39 music
```

Trying to create a directory structure to match musician's names and albums:

what I have tried:

```sh
pete@optiplex:~/tmp$ mkdir /home/pete/tmp/music/musician\ name/album\ name
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/pete/tmp/music/musician name/album name’: No such file or directory

pete@optiplex:~/tmp$ mkdir "/home/pete/tmp/music/musician name/album name"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/pete/tmp/music/musician name/album name’: No such file or directory

pete@optiplex:~/tmp$ mkdir /home/pete/tmp/music/musician\ name/album
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/pete/tmp/music/musician name/album’: No such file or directory

pete@optiplex:~/tmp$ mkdir /home/pete/tmp/music/musician\ name
```

this does work without adding the album name

conclusion:
after escaping no further directories can be created

Comment: You probably want to do this from a shell, but which shell is it? BTW: Have you tried doing this without any spaces in the name at all? That would get you closer to a [mcve], which is actually required for questions here. Further, consider looking in the manpage of `mkdir` for possible solutions. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is unrelated to the space in the directory name.  For spaces in file names or directory names, double quotes is probably the most robust so you can substitute out the hard coded path names for variables in the future.  If you have a space in the variable path name, you will need quotes around the variable, but you won't (practically) be able to toss in the required backslashes to escape all the spaces.  The issue is the parent directories don't exist.  If you want to make a directory structure `foo/bar`:

```
# will fail if foo does not exist.
mkdir foo/bar
```

What you are looking for is `mkdir`'s `-p (--parents)` option.  This will create the directory plus any parent directories that do not exist.  From `mkdir --help`:

```
-p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

I would also add the `-v (--verbose)` option as well so you can get some output detailing what was done.  So in your specific example, you would want to do something like this:

```
mkdir -vp "/home/pete/tmp/music/musician name/album name"
```

If you wanted to add this to a script and use a variable in its place, you would still be able to accomplish this with double quotes:

```
musician_name="musician name"
album_name="album name"
mkdir -vp "/home/pete/tmp/music/${musician_name}/${album_name}"
```

Comment: The mkdir -p flag was the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try assigning the directory name to a variable and then calling the mkdir command.

For eg.

```
dir='/home/pete/tmp/music/musician name/album name'
mkdir -p "$dir"
```

Comment: The `-p` is the key here, not the alternative method for specify the path.

Comment: @chepner -p to make parent directories.

Comment: Yes; I mean `mkdir -p /home/pete/tmp/music/musician\ name/album\ name` would work as well, in line with the OP's other attempts. He didn't have a quoting problem, just a usage problem with `mkdir`.

Comment: @chepner Oh got it, Thanks